# How to setup /var/log/container in kubernetes single node cluster with kubeadm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I've installed a single node cluster with kubeadm but the log symlink on /var/log/containers is empty.
What I need to do to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On machines with systemd, the kubelet and container runtime write to `journald`. Check if your log output runs to `journald`. By defoult it should write those logs to `json.log` files but I don't know any specifics of your setup. Check `/etc/sysconfig/` for `--log-driver=journald` and delete it if needed. What we want here is to have the log driver set to `json`. Therefore you would see the logs files in `/var/log/containers`.

Please let me know if that helped.